# problem with Input() function when don`t want user enter number

Tags: python, python-3.x

i wrote an script , i want to know how to prevent when user enter number i show a message 'number is not OK! just string') .
Thanks.

```
#! /usr/bin/ipython3
a=input('Please enter your Name : ')
if a=='mohammadreza':
    print("    ")
    print ('i found you finally')
    print("    ")
elif a=='':
    print ('Null name is not ok!')
else:
    print ('No you are not that person')
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please, provide [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Code)

Comment: Kindly paste the code here

Comment: would mohammadreza123 be okay?

Answer (score 0):

You have a string. And if you want to check if it is a number, you can use the following code:

```
a.replace('.','',1).isdigit()
```

So you can create a new elif like this:

```
elif a.replace('.','',1).isdigit():
    print("number is not OK! just string")
```

Comment: Why the `replace`?

Comment: With the method isdigit(), you get only true if it is an integer. So if the string contains a dot from a decimal number, the method return false. To solve this problem you can replace the dot.

Answer (score 0):

problem here is `input` always return a string. `isdigit` handle this for you but it fails with floats (this is the reason behind "replace . solution").
Another approach could be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def is_a_number(s):
    '''try to convert a string to int and float'''
    try:
        int(s)
        return True
    except:
        pass

    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except:
        pass

    return False


def main():
    a=input('Please enter your Name : ')

    if a=='foo':
        print ('i found you finally')
    elif is_a_number(a):
        print('number is not OK! just string')
    elif a=='':
        print ('Null name is not ok!')
    else:
        print ('No you are not that person')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You only need to try the conversion to `float`. Strings containing digits which are convertible to `int` are convertible to `float` as well (the opposite is not true).